# How to allow raycasting when the player is at a certain distance from object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've implemented opening drawers/doors features on my game but the issue I'm facing is that when The player opens a drawer, it gets pushed back so the drawer has some room to be opened. sometimes it jitters when pushed back.

```
 Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, 3f); 
        if (hit.transform)
        {
            interactiveObjects = hit.transform.GetComponent<InteractiveObjects>();
        }
        else
        {
            lookObject = null;
            interactiveObjects = null;
        }
        if (Open)
        {
            if (interactiveObjects)
            {
                interactiveObjects.OnOpen();
            }
        }
```

I'm using `raycast` to open the drawer. Is there a way to only allow the raycasting, when the player is not too close to the drawer? so it doesn't get pushed back by the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the distance after doing the raycast.  If the distance is within the tolerable range, execute the rest of your code.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, 3f))
{
    if (hit.distance >= minDistance)
    {
         // Code to execute when range is acceptable
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Player is too close to object!");
    }
}
```

The distance used above does not take into account the height difference between the hit point and the camera.  You can get a much more consistent distance by setting the y component of both vectors equal before getting the distance.

```
var cameraPos = mainCamera.transform.position;
cameraPos.y = hit.point.y;

var distance = Vector3.Distance(hit.point, cameraPos);
```

Comment: it worked but only for the upper drawers, for lower drawers, they are still opening even if the player is too close. I think because the raycasting distance from the camera to the drawers are different as the lower drawers has bigger distance.

Comment: Yeah, the distance is relative to the camera.  What you can do is calculate the distance between the hit position and the camera position with y set to the hit y.

Comment: can I calculate the position of the player? it would be easier

Comment: I updated the answer to get a more consistent distance.  I do not know what you mean by calculate the position of the player.  Do you mean the distance from the player to the hit object?  If so, you can use the same code i just added and replace `mainCamera.transform.position` with `myPlayer.transform.position`, however they will do the same thing (though may differ in actual distance).